# Rebalance topology throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: twitter, apache-storm

I'm using the Taylor Goetz's storm version pointed out by article

http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/12/18/running-apache-storm-on-windows/

and located at:
https://github.com/ptgoetz/incubator-storm/tree/windows-test

I have succeeded to install everything on my computer (running windows 7, 64 bit). I have also ran fine the indicated topology and my topology too. But when I'm trying to do a rebalancing of my topology by re-configuring the number of spouts or bolt with the command

```
storm rebalance WordCount -e spout=3
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out   of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
at backtype.storm.command.rebalance$parse_executor.invoke(rebalance.clj:24)
at clojure.tools.cli$apply_specs.invoke(cli.clj:80)
at clojure.tools.cli$cli.doInvoke(cli.clj:130)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
at backtype.storm.command.rebalance$_main.doInvoke(rebalance.clj:31)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at backtype.storm.command.rebalance.main(Unknown Source)
```

If I'm changing only the number of workers it works without any exceptions.

If someone of you have tested this version, can you please help me to get rid of it?
I'll look forward for your answers.

Comment: I removed a signature during my edit, just in case you're wondering - they're not used on StackOverflow. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @Cris Thanks, Chris for formatting my code and for the comments.   The issue is in the rebalance.clj in the parse-excutor function, where the input string doesn't come correctly. If I'm sending    "-e mybolt=5" the function receives only "mybolt" instead of "mybolt=5"

Comment: just wondering whether spout is a component name???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mentioned version for Windows, the  rebalance command arguments should not be passed as indicated in

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology

```
storm rebalance mytopology -n 5 -e blue-spout=3 -e yellow-bolt=10
```

In order to get rid of the mentioned exception(java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:) you should use the command

```
 storm rebalance WordCount -e "spout=3"
```

However, trying to rebalance more components (either spouts or bolts) will rebalance only the latest component mentioned in the list. So, for example for example:

```
storm rebalance WordCount -e "spout=3" -e "count=5"
```

the rebalance will be applied only for the "count" component not for the "spout".

So, in my opinion either the documentation should be updated or the rebalance.clj should be changed in order to support rebalancing for multiple components.
But this is a different issue.

Comment: Taylor Goetz added a jira issue concerning this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-214